# $resource function $save(), what exactly does, How it support CRUD operations on server-side data

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

Have a doubt in angular resource, In this document [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/%24resource)

Given :

```
var User = $resource('/user/:userId', {userId:'@id'});
     User.get({userId:123}, function(user) {
       user.abc = true;
       user.$save(); //Doubt here.
     });
```

Just above this they have given

> "When the data is returned from the server then the object is an
>   instance of the resource type and all of the non-GET methods are
>   available with `$` prefix. This allows you to easily support **CRUD
>   operations (create, read, update, delete) on server-side data.**"

Now consider for example, i have a PHP script `/user` which performs some operation like insert a record to Mysql Database.

My assumptions :
*`.$save()`*, does it save/update, automatically to Database internally with a update statement?, (i do not think So). Also please clarify, How itsupports **CRUD operations**  from client-side-programming.

or, Does this mean the assignment operation `user.abc = true` should be saved to object. (NOT required, just assigning a value to a object property is enough).

Then What is this **`$save()` Exactly, doing in a client-side- programming.**

Comment: given your endpoint `/users`, does it allow `POST` ? `$save` will `POST` the data you have set as model `user`. These methods require that your server is set up this way .. are they ?

Comment: ie - `$save` is an abstraction method on the model object for an ajax request, - sent to your server with the http verb 'POST`

Answer (score 0):

These are just conventions that the `$resource` object follows.

`$save or save` would do a HTTP POST with the model data, on the resource url.

`$delete or delete` make a HTTP DELETE request on the resource url.

and developers many times add `update` which does a HTTP PUT on the resource url.

**The server still needs to implementation this and provide basic CRUD operation support.**

In standard RESTful service (server) the conventions are like

`Url: /users  Action:GET`
would get all user resources

`Url: /users/1 Action:GET`
would get the user resource with identifier `1`

`Url:/users  Action:POST`
should create a new user resource on server

`Url: /users/1 Action:PUT`
should update the user details for user with id `1`

And the client side `$resource` is modeled around these convention